# How to use conditions in while loop in Node JS which has a asynchronous query function with loop conditions modified only in callback functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

In my nodejs program, the while loop has conditions that can be modified by asynchronous function inside it. But, as the function is asynchronous, the program is going in infinite loop. How to go around this?

```
let unique = true
while(unique)
{
    console.log("Inside Loop")
    let id = random.generate(5)
    let u_query = "Insert into table_db (id, name) values ("+db.escape(id)+", "+db.escape(name)+")";
    db.query(u_query, (error, results, fields) => {
        console.log("Inside Query")
        if(error)
        {
            if(error.code !== 'ER_DUP_ENTRY')
                throw error
        }
        else
        {
            unique = false // to stop execution
            res.send("Shorted URL : "+newURL)
            // break is giving error
            //SyntaxError: Illegal break statement
        }
    })
    // To check if loop is stopping and asynch function is causing infinite loop
    // I used unique = false here
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [recursion](https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/) to make sure that all db queries run synchronously, here is an example:

```
function nextQuery() {

    let id = random.generate(5)
    let u_query = "Insert into table_db (id, name) values ("+db.escape(id)+", "+db.escape(name)+")";

    db.query(u_query, (error, results, fields) => {

        if (error) {

            if (error.code !== 'ER_DUP_ENTRY')
                throw error

            // call nextQuery()
            return nextQuery();
        }
        else {

            return res.send("Shorted URL : "+newURL) // to stop execution
        }

    })
}

nextQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `async/await` on node > `7.9.0`, like that:

```
const whatever = async () => {
    let unique = true
    while(unique)
    {
        const id = random.generate(5)
        const u_query = `Insert into table_db (id, name) values (${db.escape(id)}, ${db.escape(name)})`

        await new Promise(resolve => db.query(u_query, error => {
            if(error) {
                if(error.code !== 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') throw error
            } else {
                unique = false
                res.send('Shorted URL : ' + newURL)
            }

            resolve()
        }))
    }
}
```

`await`ing a `new Promise` will suspend your function until the promise resolves. It will not block the main thread.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but it seems like you are trying to create your own unique id. I think that whatever db you're using can handle it for you. Just take the time to search through the docs of the db/driver you're using. Trying to generate a unique id the way you're doing it seems very inefficient.